# I'm getting started with testing in Rails, and I'm unsure of my tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, tdd

I've been trying to become a proper TDD dude. I've set up Rspec, FactoryGirl, and some basic tests on my model. All of these tests are validating for presence on my Plantask model.

I've moved my Factory to a before block, which was some minor refactoring, but since I'm new to testing, I'd like some advice on how to improve my tests. I'm not experienced enough yet to know if they are even really "DRY".

**In my model:**

validates :area_id, presence: true # Add so on.

**My tests:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Plantask do
    before(:each) do
        @plantask = FactoryGirl.create(:plantask)
    end

    it "is valid with valid attributes" do
        @plantask.should be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without an area" do
        @plantask.area_id = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without equipment" do
        @plantask.equipment_id = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a part" do
        @plantask.part_id = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a description" do
        @plantask.description = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a datatype" do
        @plantask.datatype_id = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without an assignment" do
        @plantask.assigned = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without an associate" do
        @plantask.associate_id = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

    it "is invalid without a number" do
        @plantask.number = nil
        @plantask.should_not be_valid
    end

end
```

Alright, thanks you guys. Now I have this, which is much more compact. Way cool.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Plantask do

subject (:plantask) { FactoryGirl.create(:plantask) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:area_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:equipment_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:part_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:description) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:datatype_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:assigned) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:associate_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:procedure_id) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:recurrence) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:number) }

  it { should be_valid }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of test, I recommend you to use the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem, which will help you to clean your code.

This will look like this:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:area_id) }
it { should validate_presence_of(:equipment_id) }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

use subject  https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/subject/explicit-subject

```
describe Plantask do

  subject (:plantask) { FactoryGirl.create(:plantask) }

  it { should be_valid }
  ...
end
```